# How to combine Views, Rules and EVA to record submission?

Tags: 7, views, rules, users, forms

I have a Drupal 7 site and I'm using Views, Rules and EVA.

I have a specific requirement that I am sure can be achieved with the modules, but I am having no joy configuring a working process.

I have an 'Application' content type, which has a submission form embedded (i.e. visitor completes submission form for the role they are applying for).

As all visitors login in order to submit an application, I would like to record each application they make into a 'My Applications' view/block, within their User (/user) page.

I see the process as something along the lines of:

1. Visitor completes application form and clicks a Submit button.
2. Via Rules, an association/reference between the user and the specific role/application is recorded.
3. Using EVA, a custom view will list the applications the user has made (showing only his/her applications, unless admin).

The part I am failing with is how to configure a Rule, triggered by the submit button, that links the user to the specific application, in such a way that it can then form the EVA view.

Has anybody implemented a similar process? Recording applications (for jobs, events, meetings etc) and allowing users to see those they have applied for must be possible?

I would be happy to use an entirely different approach if there is a better method vs. the  Views/Rules/EVA idea.

Suggestions gratefully received. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with EVA but it looks pretty good.

I have a similar use case with [entityform](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform).

You can [embed entityforms on nodes](http://www.sixmiletech.com/content/embedding-entiyform-node) using the entityreference field.

Now entityform comes with a view already set up that displays a user's latest entityforms.

Here is a screencap of the view configuration - it displays a user's latest form submission(s).

[image: A view configured to display a user's latest form submission(s)]

You can then add a 'block' version of this view (the 'add' button in the top left corner.)

You can then configure your new block [to **only** show up on the logged-in-user's /user page.](https://www.drupal.org/node/134433)

[image]

Hope that helps. Incidentally let me know if you are trying to get the form-fields to be pre-populated with user details.

Based on your comments:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yea this is a good use-case for entityform + views.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply Iain. I've not looked at entityform before, so I'll take a look over the documentation and test it out on a staging site. I'll perhaps come back to you, as some of the fields will require populating from existing data stored in the user profile, but perhaps I can sort that via tokens. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @iain-maitland - I created the form via entityform and submitted test entries with a standard user account. That aspect works fine and if I go to admin/structure/entityform_types and click Submissions, I see those posted. However, the block (added as you suggested within the view and assigned this to a region) does not display. Even if I remove all restrictions, showing the block to all users on all pages, it fails to display. I have cleared all caches. Because data is visible in the admin/structure/entityform_types page, I'm sure the form is fine. Can you think what may cause this? Thanks

Comment: I realised that the Contextual Filter 'Entityform Submission: Entityform Type' had a Hide View condition, if the filter is not available. I removed this filter for the block. Now I get the default 'No results behavior' text ("No entityforms have been created yet"). However, even if I login with a user account that has submitted entity forms, I still get the No Results behaviour text. Please can you tell me how you configured the Block view, in order to successfully display the submissions for the user logged in? Thank you

Comment: Hi MCG, i've added 2 screen caps for you of this set up on a production site. Not sure i was remiss in suggesting the contextual filter be 'entityform:type' I don't have the time to review my original answer. In the example I've just added it's set to 'User ID'. Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you very much Iain, your screenshots are very helpful. I appreciate the help you provided to enable me to get the view working.